# How to access a website despite a certificate error?

Tags: dns, web-browser, certificate

I am moving a web server to a new infrastructure. Before switching the DNS records I would like to check if the new configuration is working. I modified `/private/etc/hosts/` with the IP addresses (IPv4 and IPv6) of the new server and after flushing the DNS cache everything is working.

But as the certificate doesn't match, Safari, Firefox, Opera and Chrome give me an error which I can't seem to ignore. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Google Chrome the following flag exists to circumvent certificate errors and continue browsing:

1. Close Google Chrome
2. Open Terminal and enter:

   ```
   /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --ignore-certificate-errors &> /dev/null &
   ```

   If the app resides somewhere else than in */Applications/* apply the path to *Google Chrome* respectively.

Launching Google Chrome like this is rather meant for dev purposes than for normal browsing since the security of the https-connection(s) is flawed.